# UserNamePasswordValidator catch exception

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I have a `UserNamePasswordValidator`:

```
 public class EmployeeValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
 {
    public override void Validate(String userName, String password)
    {
        //...
        throw new MessageSecurityException("Username and password cannot be empty.");
        //...         
    }
 }
```

In the `ViewModel`:

```
private void Login()
{
     try
     {
          _cl.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
          _cl.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = UserName;
          _cl.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Password;
          _cl.Login(UserName)
     }
     catch
     {  /*...*/  }
}
```

The problem is, that I cannot catch the exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you got MessageSecurity enabled? Configured in your bindings? Are you hitting the service?

Answer (score 0):

fire up fiddler, i bet the code is 501 (maybe 500 long time since i looked at this), then search for how to rewrite the error code in wcf.

If it is something other than 501 then your connection will not be aborted and you may be able to handle the error (fault) properly